# Difference in following two assigning's

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is difference in following to assignments

```
case 'INCREASE_EQUIPMENT_QUANTITY': {
  const myData = data.equipmentList.map((equipment, selected) => {
    return(data.index === selected && equipment._quantity < equipment._qty ?  equipment._quantity = equipment._quantity + 1 : equipment);
  });
  return state.merge({
    equipment: myData
  });
}
```

---

```
case 'INCREASE_EQUIPMENT_QUANTITY': {
  data.equipmentList.map((equipment, selected) => {
    return(data.index === selected && equipment._quantity < equipment._qty ?  equipment._quantity = equipment._quantity + 1 : equipment);
  });
  return state.merge({
    equipment: data.equipmentList
  });
}
```

Comment: `here i am getting my array with wrong objects` What does that mean? What's the expected output? What's the difference between the two?

Comment: In the first statement, `myData` contains the return of the  execution of `map`. So if the result is wrong, it's the statement in the `map` function that is wrong. In the second statement, the result of `map` is not stored and the `equipmentList` array is not modified. So, if the result is correct, your `equipmenList` array content is correct. Here is the documentation about `map` function: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/map

Comment: please replace the `data.equipmentList.map(...)` part with `var equipment = data.equipmentList[data[index]];
if(equipment && equipment._quantity < equipment._qty) equipment._quantity++;` because that's what it effectively does. Your version is just obscuring that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why????

Because `.map` returns a new array containing the return values of the callback. Your callback either returns `equipment._quantity + 1` or `equipment`. So you end up with an array that contains numbers and objects, which is obviously not correct. `equipment._quantity + 1` is returned because the *result* of an *assignment* is always the value that was assigned.

Example:

```js
var foo = {};
var result = foo.bar = 42;
console.log(result);
```

You are performing the assignment `equipment._quantity = equipment._quantity + 1`.

The second one "works" because the callback mutates the objects in place (`equipment._quantity = equipment._quantity + 1`). And while `.map` *could* be used, it's semantically incorrect.

You should either:

1) Use `.map`, always return an object and create new objects when necessary (no in-place mutation):

```
const myData = data.equipmentList.map((equipment, selected) => (
  data.index === selected && equipment._quantity < equipment._qty ?
    Object.assign({}, equipment, {_quantity: equipment._quantity + 1} :
    equipment
));
```

2) Use `.forEach` instead of `.map` and mutate the objects in-place. No need to return anything, just perform the mutation when the condition is `true`:

```
const myData = data.equipmentList.forEach((equipment, selected) => {
  if (data.index === selected && equipment._quantity < equipment._qty) {
    equipement._quantity = equipment._quantity + 1;
  }
));
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this snippet, to get the issue with first one:

```js
let obj = [{a:1}, {a:2}, {a:3}, {a:4}];

let result = obj.map(el => {
    return el.a > 2 ? el.a = el.a+1 : el;
});

console.log('result = ', result);
```

If the condition will be true then you are returning `equipment._quantity`  (value) **not the equipment object**, so the result of `map` will be like this:

```
result = [{...}, {...}, value, value, {...}];
```

To solve that issue, write it like this with `map`:

```
case 'INCREASE_EQUIPMENT_QUANTITY': {

    const myData = data.equipmentList.map((equipment, selected) => {
        if(data.index === selected && equipment._quantity < equipment._qty)
            return Object.assign( {}, equipment, {_quantity: equipment._quantity + 1}) 
        return equipment;
    });

    return state.merge({
        equipment: myData
    });
}
```

Check the MDN doc for more details about [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Answer (score 1):

The first statement contains the mapped array (since the JavaScript map function returns a new array). Since the map function does not modify the original array, in the second snippet you posted, the "equipment" key refers to the original equipment list array